# Generating GeoJson, how to use NewLine?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, jsonp, geojson

I have a couple functions that take a CSV Excel sheet and convert the data into GeoJsonP, for use with a Google Maps project.  After each entry, I want to use a NewLine command so each entry will be on its own line rather than the entire file being one extremely long line.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u960.png)

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPvWT.png)

I've searched and found that using \n causes an error so multiple answers mentioned using \n instead, but this doesn't work either.  Is the only solution to overwrite the JSON.stringify function?

Comment: You should include your code in your question rather as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Using template literals is a really bad way to write JSON. You should create the structure in JS first then [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it.

You can use the stringify's [space parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) to return a string formatted to your requirements.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Bob', age: 12 },
  { name: 'Sam', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Karen', age: 45 }
];

// Without
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
 
// With
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```